# Why does scala require existential types to restrict a generic bound?

Tags: scala, types, existential-type

With the following class hierarchy:

```scala
trait Provider[A] {
  def get(): Seq[A]
}

abstract class ProviderImpl[A] extends Provider[A] {
  final override def get(): Seq[A] = Seq()
}

trait HasX {
  def getX: Int
}

trait RefinedProvider[A <: HasX] extends Provider[A]

class TypedProviderImpl extends ProviderImpl[HasX] with RefinedProvider[HasX]
```

I want to be able to do this:

```scala
val provider: RefinedProvider[_] = new TypedProviderImpl()
provider.get() map (_.getX)
```

But it doesn't work, because the return type of `provider.get()` is `Seq[Any]` which seems wrong to me because it's a `RefinedProvider`, so `get()` should return a `Seq[_ <: HasX]`.

**Question:** I can fix the problem with an existential type, but why can't the compiler enforce this for me?

```scala
val provider: RefinedProvider[T] forSome { type T <: HasX } = ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M - actually, your comments do answer it: the ticket points to the spec, which says that `A[_]` is *always* equivalent to `A[Any]` (if I'm reading right) and the compiler never applies further bounds. I'd also somehow forgotten about `[_ <: HasX]` - my use case is more complex than the above, but I can wire it through various method signatures to make it work. Do you want to make a full answer out of this?

Comment: The spec is very clear that a wildcard of `_` is `_ >: Nothing <: Any` by default. See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types , "Placeholder Syntax for Existential Types".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ticket [SI-2385](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2385) suggests this is simply part of the spec to interpret `A[_]` as `A[T] forSome
{ type T >: Nothing <: Any }` and not infer tighter bounds if possible. One could wonder whether the spec shouldn't be updated then.

Ticket [SI-6169](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6169) seems to suggest that some things would stop working if tighter bounds were inferred. I'm not sure how and why though.

A small compromise is that you can shorten

```
val provider: RefinedProvider[T] forSome { type T <: HasX }
```

to

```
val provider: RefinedProvider[_ <: HasX]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by you are using **wildcard**: `_` to state your variable type: `val provider: RefinedProvider[_]`, `_` it means **Any** type, you can do it like:

```
val provider = new TypedProviderImpl() // the compiler and IDE will auto infer **provider** type
```

or

```
val provider: RefinedProvider[HasX] = new TypedProviderImpl() // explicitly provider type
```

Comment: I think the question is, why scala don't make wildCard type HasX, while we can't put into RefinedProvider anything different than HasX and its children. For me this is mystery also :)

Comment: In OP's defence: it seems very reasonable for the compiler to interpret `RefinedProvider[_]` as `RefinedProvider[_ <: HasX]`. Since `RefinedProvider` has the constraint `A <: HasX`.

Comment: The example is simplified: in my actual use case, the `TypedProviderImpl` is a whole family of classes which are passed in via dependency injection, so I can't let the compiler type them for me, sadly.