# Why does usage of Foo[T <: Bar] require Foo[_ <: Bar] rather than Foo[_]

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type

Given

```
trait Foo[T <: Bar] {
   def foo: T
}
```

why does the compiler **NOT** interpret signature like

```
def foo(f: Foo[_])
```

to mean that the unknown `_` **must** be a type of `Bar`. Instead, it forces me to do this

```
def foo(f: Foo[_ <: Bar])
```

which complicates signatures. I'm sure the compiler must be right and I'm missing some subtlety but clearly a `Foo[X]` where `X` is **NOT** some kind of `Bar` so not possible by construction, so why?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323140/why-are-the-bounds-of-type-parameters-ignored-when-using-existential-types-in-sc

Comment: Thanks @DmytroMitin but the answer is from almost 10 years ago and it is a best-guess type of answer, would be nice to see if there is a more recent and concrete answer. Even the 2nd one with the link to the scala discussion thread itself is inconclusive. If moderators disagree I guess the question can be closed. Thanks for the thread though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696319/why-does-scala-require-existential-types-to-restrict-a-generic-bound

Comment: thanks @DmytroMitin i did a bit of investigation and i think my answer below is better than the answers in the two similar questions as it gives more up-to-date info and clearly states it looks like a legit compiler deficiency.  it also confirms Dotty works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - seems to be a deficiency of the compiler and an open question whether to address it. Fixing it may have unintended consequences but it's been raised often enough to still be considered seriously as a possible fix. Here are some of the most relevant and still open Bugs tickets.

**P.S. It seems that Dotty does honor such bounds so they may well fix it!**

- https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11491 - from Apr 17, 2019
- https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8198 - from Jan 28, 2014
- https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/1786 - from Mar 11, 2009