# underscore for generic type argument produces compile error in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, type-conversion, existential-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have

```
trait MyBase[T <: MyBase[T]] {
  def myid: String
}
```

So writing

```
case class MyBaseContainer(myBase: MyBase[_])
```

produces Type bound error for `T` in `MyBase`

```
type arguments [_$1] do not conform to trait MyBase's type parameter bounds [T <: Playground.MyBase[T]]
```

while writing it as

```
case class MyBaseContainer[T <: MyBase[_]](myBase: T)
```

compiles whiteout any errors.

Why is this happening? Aren’t these two signatures for `MyBaseContainer` semantically equivalent?

Is there a syntactical way for constraining the type parameter `MyBase` takes to the required bound, without passing `T` as a type parameter to `MyBaseContainer`?

Comment: The error message appears to explain the problem: `_` is not constrained but the type parameter to `MyBase` needs to be constrained `T <: MyBase[T]` or tighter.

Comment: @Tim Is there another syntactical way for constraining it other than passing `T` as a type parameter to `MyBaseContainer`?

Comment: I don't believe so, but not an expert

Comment: @James You can write `case class MyBaseContainer(myBase: MyBase[T] forSome {type T <: MyBase[T]})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323140/why-are-the-bounds-of-type-parameters-ignored-when-using-existential-types-in-sc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62365400/why-does-usage-of-foot-bar-require-foo-bar-rather-than-foo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696319/why-does-scala-require-existential-types-to-restrict-a-generic-bound  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911369/type-parameter-bound-not-considered-when-generic-type-is-used-with-unbounded-wil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890617/type-bound-error-when-creating-a-tuple-in-scala

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thank you very much. I edited the question to make it more specific. If you add the answer as you have commented, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Dmytro Mitin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249621/dmytro-mitin) in the comments, this would work:

```
import scala.language.existentials

case class MyBase[T <: MyBase[T]] (
   myid: String
)


case class MyBaseContainer(myBase: MyBase[T] forSome {type T <: MyBase[T]})
```